# Почему не приходят данные?

Tags: ajax, laravel

Есть CRUD приложение на Laravel.
Операция добавление записи не возвращает данные с сервера. Action отрабатывает - запись сохраняется. Почему в консоле нету данных?

шаблон

```
  @extends('master')
@section('content')
    @include('_partial.errors')
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Add new
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <label class="">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name_ajax" class="form-control">
                    <label class="">Parent_id</label>
                    <input type="text" name="parent_id" id="parent_ajax" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addNew" >Add New</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <div class=" table-responsive">

        <table class="table table-hover " id="table_result">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>N</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Parent_id</th>
                <th>Show Edit Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach($items as $item)

                <tbody>
                <th>{{$item->id}}</th>
                <th>{{$item->name}}</th>
                <th>{{$item->parent_id}}</th>
                <th>

                    {{Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE'])}}
                    {{--@method('delete')--}}
                    {{Form::button('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-block btn-danger send'])}}

                    {{Form::close()}}
                </th>
                <th>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        {{ method_field('Delete') }}
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn-success send">
                    </form>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="/ajax" class="btn btn-success btn-block ">Send Ajax</a>
                </th>
                </tbody>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>

    <p><b></b>
    </p>
@endsection
```

action

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $item = new Test($request->all());
        $item->save();
        return response()->json($item);
    }
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('.addNew').click(function (e) {
        $('.modal').modal('toggle');      
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'/index1',
            data:{
                'name':$('#name_ajax').val(),
                'parent_id':$('#parent_ajax').val()
            },
            success:function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                 // $('#table_result tr:first').after("<tr><th>'data.id'</th><th>'data.name'</th><th>'data.parent.id'</th></tr>")
            }

        })
    })

})
```

Comment: статус от сервера получаете 200?

Comment: Да 200 . Запись добавляется в базу. Ищу проблему

Comment: попробуй `return response($item);`, Хотя.. Какой ответ видишь во вкладке `Инструменты разработчика -> сеть`?

Comment: Спасибо  . С помощью дебагера  получил данные.